# Copy new project to solution, not only reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a solution with a main project and need to add another project to the solution. The problem is that if i click right on solution and "add existing project" , it only references the new project.

How can i copy the entire new project to my solution and have it's path relative? ( so that if i move the solution project anywhere, the project still works and not dependent on external references)

The same question is for references(dlls) also.

Comment: Copy project files to the target solution folder and then do `Add Existing`

Comment: Why don't you just copy the project into your solution folder and **then** add it into the solution from Visual Studio

Comment: @sll doesn't this add a non-relative path to the project?

Comment: i.e. if i do this, if i move the solution, won't the linkage to the new project still point to the location from where i've moved?